# UITableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle not called on iOS9 device

Tags: ios9

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index;

This method is working on the simulator where as in the device it doesn't invoke, tried by putting breakpoint. This is for iOS9